# Xcode not saving file associations

Tags: xcode

I go to Xcode > Preferences > file_types, change association for file type "xyz", click apply+ok, reopen Xcode > Preferences > file_types, check association for file type "xyz", its set as I just edited it.

Not I quit xcode, start it again, xcode>preferences>file_types, check association for file type "xyz", and its getting reset to its old value just like i never edited it.

This is so lame, kindly suggest something :(

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a "file type management" but this is a valid workaround:

1. Go to any file whose extension you don't want to open with Xcode (e.g. MAC.json).
2. Right click on it, select `Get Info` (or CMD I).
3. Under `Open With`, select your editor for that extension.
4. Click `Change All` to make the change global across all files of this type.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31344909)